# Zero limit in $R^n$

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

Let be $\mathbf{f}:\mathbb{R}^m\to \mathbb{R}^n$.
In my problem I start from the following given identity (=assumption):
$$
0=\lim_{\mathbf{x}\to \mathbf{\tilde{x}}}
\left\lVert
  \frac{\mathbf{f}(\mathbf{x})-\mathbf{f}(\mathbf{\tilde{x}})} 
       {\left\lVert\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{\tilde{x}}\right\rVert}
  -D\mathbf{f}_{\mathbf{\tilde{x}}}
    \frac{(\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{\tilde{x}})}
      {\left\lVert\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{\tilde{x}}\right\rVert}
\right\rVert, 
$$
meaning that $\mathbf{f}$ has a total derivative at $\mathbf{\tilde{x}}$.

I generalize the problem to 
$$\tag{*}
0=\lim_{\mathbf{x}\to \mathbf{\tilde{x}}}
\left\lVert
  \mathbf{F}(\mathbf{x})
  -M_{\mathbf{\tilde{x}}}
    \frac{(\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{\tilde{x}})}
      {\left\lVert\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{\tilde{x}}\right\rVert}
\right\rVert, 
$$
where $M_{\mathbf{\tilde{x}}}$ is a constant linear transformation $\mathbb{R}^m\to \mathbb{R}^n$ with parameter $\mathbf{\tilde{x}}$ (actually the parameter is not relevant) and $\mathbf{F}(\mathbf{x})$ is a map $\mathbb{R}^m\to \mathbb{R}^n$.

> 1) Can I conclude from (*) that 
>   $$
> \mathbf{0}=\lim_{\mathbf{x}\to \mathbf{\tilde{x}}}
> \left(
>   \mathbf{F}(\mathbf{x})
>   -M_{\mathbf{\tilde{x}}}
>     \frac{(\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{\tilde{x}})}
>       {\left\lVert\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{\tilde{x}}\right\rVert}
> \right)?
> $$
>   2) Can I conclude from (*) that 
>   $$
> \lim_{\mathbf{x}\to \mathbf{\tilde{x}}}
>   \mathbf{F}(\mathbf{x})
> =\lim_{\mathbf{x}\to \mathbf{\tilde{x}}}
>   M_{\mathbf{\tilde{x}}}
>     \frac{(\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{\tilde{x}})}
>       {\left\lVert\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{\tilde{x}}\right\rVert}?
> $$
>   3) Can I conclude from (*) that 
>   $$
> \lim_{\mathbf{x}\to \mathbf{\tilde{x}}}
>   \left\lVert\mathbf{F}(\mathbf{x})\right\rVert
> =\lim_{\mathbf{x}\to \mathbf{\tilde{x}}}
>   \left\lVert M_{\mathbf{\tilde{x}}}
>     \frac{(\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{\tilde{x}})}
>       {\left\lVert\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{\tilde{x}}\right\rVert}\right\rVert?
> $$
>   $M_{\mathbf{\tilde{x}}}$ is applied on a unit vector that could spiral on the path to the limit.

Answer (score 0):

- (*) is equivalent to (1). This is immediately obvious from the $\varepsilon$-$\delta$ definitions of limits. (There's nothing much to prove here).
- If you assume that both the limits appearing in (2) exist, then (2) follows from (1), because the limit of a difference equals the difference of the limits.
- (3) follows from (2), because the norm function $\lVert \cdot \rVert: \mathbb{R^n} \to \mathbb{R_{\geq0}}$ is continuous, which means you can pull limits in and out of the norm. Thus,
  \begin{align}
  \lim_{x \to \tilde{x}} \lVert F(x) \rVert &= \bigg\lVert \lim_{x \to \tilde{x}} F(x) \bigg\rVert \\
  &= \bigg\lVert \lim_{x \to \tilde{x}} M_{\tilde{x}} \dfrac{x - \tilde{x}}{\lVert x - \tilde{x} \rVert} \bigg\rVert \\
  &= \lim_{x \to \tilde{x}} \bigg\lVert  M_{\tilde{x}} \dfrac{x - \tilde{x}}{\lVert x - \tilde{x} \rVert} \bigg\rVert.
  \end{align} 
  So yes, assuming all the limits exist, we have $(*) \implies (1) \implies (2) \implies (3)$.